# React sort by price menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, object, filtering

I am making an e-commerce with two menus: filter by category and sort by price (high to low and vice versa). I've already made a filter menu, but I am not sure how to create a sort by price menu. I successfully achieved it with plain JavaScript, but I'm having some troubles understanding how to do it in React since I am still a bit new to its logics.

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import "./VinylClocks.css";
import Navbar from "./Navbar.jsx";
import Footer from "./Footer.jsx";
import SortButton from "./SortButton.jsx";
import {data} from './data.js';
import Product from "./Product.jsx";

export default function VinylClocks() {

  const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([]);

  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState();

  // Add default value on page load
  useEffect(() => {
    setDataList(data);
  }, []);

  // Function to get filtered list
  function getFilteredList() {
    // Avoid filter when selectedCategory is null
    if (!selectedCategory) {
      return dataList;
    }
    return dataList.filter((item) => item.cat === selectedCategory);
  }

  // Avoid duplicate function calls with useMemo
  var filteredList = useMemo(getFilteredList, [selectedCategory, dataList]);

  function handleCategoryChange(event) {
    setSelectedCategory(event.target.value);
  }
    return (
      <>
        <header className="header">
          <Navbar />
        </header>  
        <div className="vc-container">
          <div className="filter-sort">
            <div className="filter-container">
              <h5>Filter by Category:</h5>
              <select
              name="cat-list"
              id="cat-list"
              onChange={handleCategoryChange}
              >
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option value="movies">Movies</option>
                <option value="music">Music</option>
                <option value="sport">Sport</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <SortButton /> 
            
          </div> 
          <div className="products-container">
          {filteredList.map((items, id) => (
      <Product {...items} key={id} />
    ))}  
          </div>
        </div>  
          <Footer />
      </>
    );
  }
```

Here is the Sort menu component:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faArrowDownWideShort } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { useState } from 'react';
import "./SortButton.css";


export default function SortButton() {
    
const [select, setSelect] = useState("");
    return (
        <>
          <div className="sort-dropdown">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowDownWideShort} style={{color: "#021027",}} />
                <select value={select} 
                onChange={e=>setSelect(e.target.value)}>
                    <option>Sort by: Latest</option>
                    <option>Sort by: Price:High to Low</option>
                    <option>Sort by: Price:Low to High</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement sorting by price in your React application, you can modify your `VinylClocks` component to include a state for sorting and create a function to handle the sorting logic. Here's an example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import "./VinylClocks.css";
import Navbar from "./Navbar.jsx";
import Footer from "./Footer.jsx";
import SortButton from "./SortButton.jsx";
import { data } from "./data.js";
import Product from "./Product.jsx";

export default function VinylClocks() {
  const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState("");
  const [sortOption, setSortOption] = useState("latest");

  // Add default value on page load
  useEffect(() => {
    setDataList(data);
  }, []);

  // Function to get filtered and sorted list
  function getFilteredAndSortedList() {
    let filteredList = dataList;
    // Filter by category
    if (selectedCategory) {
      filteredList = dataList.filter((item) => item.cat === selectedCategory);
    }

    // Sort by price
    switch (sortOption) {
      case "highToLow":
        filteredList.sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price);
        break;
      case "lowToHigh":
        filteredList.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
        break;
      // Add other cases for additional sort options if needed
      default:
        // Latest or default sorting
        // You can add more cases or modify this based on your requirements
        break;
    }

    return filteredList;
  }

  // Avoid duplicate function calls with useMemo
  var filteredAndSortedList = useMemo(getFilteredAndSortedList, [
    selectedCategory,
    sortOption,
    dataList,
  ]);

  function handleCategoryChange(event) {
    setSelectedCategory(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleSortChange(option) {
    setSortOption(option);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <header className="header">
        <Navbar />
      </header>
      <div className="vc-container">
        <div className="filter-sort">
          <div className="filter-container">
            <h5>Filter by Category:</h5>
            <select
              name="cat-list"
              id="cat-list"
              onChange={handleCategoryChange}
              value={selectedCategory}
            >
              <option value="">All</option>
              <option value="movies">Movies</option>
              <option value="music">Music</option>
              <option value="sport">Sport</option>
              <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <SortButton onSortChange={handleSortChange} />

        </div>
        <div className="products-container">
          {filteredAndSortedList.map((item, id) => (
            <Product {...item} key={id} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

And modify your `SortButton` component to call the `onSortChange` prop when the user selects a different sorting option:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faArrowDownWideShort } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./SortButton.css";

export default function SortButton({ onSortChange }) {
  const [select, setSelect] = useState("");

  function handleSortChange(e) {
    setSelect(e.target.value);
    onSortChange(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="sort-dropdown">
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          icon={faArrowDownWideShort}
          style={{ color: "#021027" }}
        />
        <select value={select} onChange={handleSortChange}>
          <option value="latest">Sort by: Latest</option>
          <option value="highToLow">Sort by: Price: High to Low</option>
          <option value="lowToHigh">Sort by: Price: Low to High</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

With these changes, the `VinylClocks` component will now handle both filtering by category and sorting by price. The `SortButton` component sends the selected sorting option back to the parent component via the `onSortChange` prop, triggering the sorting logic in the parent component.

Comment: Thanks A LOT! Still getting used to hooks.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could help. If you have any more questions or if there's anything else you'd like assistance with, feel free to ask. Happy coding!

Comment: Hello, again. I decided to use your helpfulness and ask one more question. :D I am trying to make a specific product page where the product, which is previously clicked on, will open in another page with more details about it, but it didn't work by creating new component. I saw something about Router Switch, but again, having some trouble understanding how the switch part works (I am familiar with router since i've been using it for some time now). The code above is still the same.

Comment: I would suggest that you create a new question for a better solution. You can use `react-router-dom` and follow their documentation's Switch and Route steps.